# Calculate points on earth along an isochrone (from a satellite)

Tags: geometry, satellite

Looking to calculate a set of locations on the ground that have the same time delay to a satellite in orbit (GEO, MEO, or LEO).  Any pointers to some geometry formulas that can help?  I would like to factor in the oblateness of the earth.  I suppose I can do this trial and error, but hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: "Same time delay" is quite aproximately "same distance". So an sphere centered at the satellite represents that "same distance". Intersect it with Earth's surface and you're done.

Comment: @Ripi2:  Agreed.  I'm looking for the math details on how to do that, including the oblateness of the earth.

Comment: [Some posts here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=sphere+-+sphere+intersection) About the oblateness, i'm not sure. Perhaps you can use a different Earth's radius where you suspect the sphere-sphere intesection lies. Or you can download some global data and do your own triangulation and use it to intersect with satellite sphere.